# Phrase search on PostgreSQL 11 using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, full-text-search, npgsql

I've implemented Full Text on **PostgreSQL 11** using an API made with **.NET Core 3** and **Entity Framework Core 3**.

I'm able to filter with a single word, but as soon as I use **two or more words** it doesn't work anymore.

I've tried using the **proximity operator** <->, using also 10~20 words distance, like <10> between each word, but it doesn't work, and I don't get any result back.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<List<QuestionListItemSearch>> SearchQuestions(string search)
{
    search = search.Replace(" ", "<20>");
        return await (from uiEnt in base.context.UserInfos
                      join efq in base.context.ExpertsForumQuestions on uiEnt.UserInfoId equals efq.UserInfoId
                      join efa in base.context.ExpertsForumAnswers on efq.ExpertsForumQuestionId equals efa.ExpertsForumQuestionId into ExpertsForum
                      from n in ExpertsForum.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where efq.SearchVector.Matches(search)

                      group new { uiEnt, efq, n } by new { 
                          uiEnt.FirstName, 
                          uiEnt.LastName, 
                          efq.ExpertsForumQuestionId, 
                          efq.Title, 
                          efq.Description, 
                          efq.SubmissionDate,
                          SearchRanking = efq.SearchVector.Rank(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery(search)) } into newGroup

                      select new QuestionListItemSearch
                      {
                          ExpertsForumQuestionId = newGroup.Key.ExpertsForumQuestionId,
                          Title = newGroup.Key.Title,
                          Description = newGroup.Key.Description,
                          SubmissionDate = newGroup.Key.SubmissionDate,
                          FirstNameSubmitter = newGroup.Key.FirstName,
                          LastNameSubmitter = newGroup.Key.LastName,
                          NumberOfAnswers = newGroup.Max(x => x.n.ExpertsForumAnswerId) == null ? 0 : newGroup.Count(),
                          SearchRanking = newGroup.Key.SearchRanking
                      }).OrderByDescending(q => q.SearchRanking).ToListAsync();
    

}
```

I've tried directly the query to PostgreSQL using SQL but I can't get any result:

```
SELECT "Title", "SearchVector", ts_rank(c."SearchVector", to_tsquery('crop<10>rotation')) FROM PUBLIC."ExpertsForumQuestions" c
WHERE (c."SearchVector" @@ to_tsquery('crop<10>rotation'))
```

Please note that the database has several records with both *crop* and *rotation* words in the text. There is also a record containing the two words close to each other "crop rotation"

Using the operator | instead of the proximity operator it works.

Is there a simple way to perform a phase search like in Microsoft SQL Server?